# Flexbox - numbered list <ol> - 2 columns - numbers from top to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to figure out how to split numbered list `<ol>` into 2 columns and show the numbers from top to bottom.

I've got a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qtr6mjf3/

I'm using `flex` 50% for this to split the columns into 2.

The problem is that it now shows the numbers ordered as:

1 - 2
3 - 4

Is it possible to reorder the list items, so the list shows as?:

1 - 3
2 - 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `display:flex` at ol level and give it a `column:count`, your code is able to do what you are after.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface');
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-count: 2;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Tempore nostrum laborum sequi obcaecati.</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
  <li>Amet odio rerum alias impedit!</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
  <li>Illo iusto dolores magnam ratione!</li>
</ol>
```

Browser support for `column:count` can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

Comment: Ah yes, that works great now. Many thanks for your help @Syfer

Answer (score 0):

2 columns and show the numbers from top to bottom.
you should try this, I think these codes will help you and I have also given an example.
Example:-
https://jsfiddle.net/kapil284/h2v4d7qc/

```css
.gallery-section{
  padding: 60px 0; 
} 
.gallery-section .gallery-box{
  background: #fff;
  /* column-width: 300px; */
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.gallery-section .gallery-box .box{
    display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e8ce93;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap4 -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     
    
  
<div class="gallery-section">
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="gallery-box">
        <li class="box">
          <p>1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>2.Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>3.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>4.nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>5.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>6.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          <p>7.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
        </li>


      </ol>

    </div>
  </div>
```